# Change cell reference based on slected option

Tags: vba

I am trying to change the cell reference based on the selected option.I used two methods. Both of them did not work. Can you please check my code? I have "Option Explicit" on my code. I just did not copy it here.

```
'first method
Function LM(n As Integer) As Long
    LM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M").Range("a4").Offset(0, 6 + n).Column
End Function

Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Value = "Qtr"
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(M!R[4]C" &  LM(n) & _
        "+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0)),0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

'Second option

If Option1 = true then n=6

Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Value = "Qtr"
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(M!R[4]C" & n & _
        "+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0)),0)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
Loop
```

Thank You

Comment: the first two line of the code is outside the box. please start from the 'first method

Comment: What do you mean "they don't work"? Does your code produce an error, or does it do something wrong?

Comment: for the first method, even when I say n = 4, the macro picks up column 6 instead of picking column 6+n = 10.

Comment: OK, that first function **makes no sense at all**. It will **always** give you n+7 as a result. (The number of the column that is 6+n columns to the right from col. 1=1+6+n) If it goes wrong, it goes wrong somewhere else.

Comment: And what's wrong with the second then?

Comment: I am getting this error: Application defined or object defined error. Even after, I defined n as integer

Comment: Well, I can't read your mind and I don't see your screen. **Which line produces the error?** I cannot reproduce, for me it produces no error. Try stepping through the code with `F8` to see what happens, maybe your Excel sheet has only one column, in which case `.End(xlToRight).Offset(0,1)` will of course produce an error... Help me help you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.FormulaR1C1` for a `R[]C[]` formula assignment i.e.

```
`ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(M!R[4]C" &  LM(n) & _
    "+INDEX(A!R3C4:R418C27,MATCH(M!R2C,A!R2C4:R2C27,0)),0)"`
```

In your comment you said `n` is always 6 but you have this line in your code

```
If Option1 = true then n=6
```

Check the `Option1` procedures, or show us whats that.

The function `LM()` seems just to find the column number by offset `6+n` columns from `[A4]`. It is uncessary as it is simply `4+6+n`.

Hope this helps.